# How to search for a string that contains no whitespace in perl

Tags: perl

```
my $string3 = "anima ls";
my $t3 = $string3 =~ /[^\s]+/;
print "$t3\n";
```

I wanted to write a regex that searches for a string containing no whitespace. The above code works even if i give space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `[^\s]+` searches for at least one character that is not whitespace. It is better written as `\S+`, though. A regex that matches any string that does not contain a whitespace character is rather

```
/^\S+$/
```

Comment: Thanks . what does $ do in /^\S+$/. Is it to tell to search for whitespace at the end of the string

Comment: @Angus: `^` is the beginning, `$` the end of the string. Between them, there is one or more non-whitespace.